# Can't covert excel float date (date with time) in power automate when saving to Dataverse table

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

Can't find any help when parsing Excel date number with float number.

[image]

Comment: When you extract the data from Excel, you can specify the date format you want them to be provided in. Does that not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it for you but it may be a second out depending on the rounding.

The issue is that the `addSeconds()` expression only takes an integer so once the seconds are determined, the remainder will need to be removed in order to get the expression to work.

```
addSeconds('1899-12-30T00:00:00Z', int(split(string(mul(variables('Date As Float'), 86400)), '.')[0]))
```

To test this, I created a `Float` variable called `Date As Float` with the date serial value you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Urm... You can specify `DateTime Format` in the Advanced options of the action.

[image]

Comment: Oops, sorry @Skin, just saw your comment on the same, under the question.

Comment: All good, I gave the OP another option via expressions depending on how the data is being retrieved.  Both answers may help someone in the future so it's a good outcome regardless I think.